# Android: MultiServer Issue

Tags: android, performance, multiple-instances

I have made NEWS Application in android.I have used Private Server which provide news feed to news application at client side when client make requset to get news feeds.

At a time,My server handles only 150 request exctly.But if at a time 1000 client made same request on server from devices, it gives MAX_CONNECTION ERROR.

is there any trick to handle such kind of situations? If you know please help me..